# NodeJS MySQL pool dies without throw exceptions

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, connection-pooling

After a random time, mysql pool dies without throw exceptions, and the webapp goes on refusing any user connections.
I placed some logs in my code:

```
_logger.debug("[findUser] " + queryString);
this.mysqlConn.getConnection(
    function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            _logger.error(err);
            return callback(err, null);
        }

        _logger.debug("[MySQLHandler#query] Opened connection: " + connection.threadId);
        connection.query(queryString, params, function (err, success) {
            connection.release();

            if (err) {
                _logger.error(err);
                return callback(err, null);
            }
            return callback(null, success);
        });
    }
);
```

When the pool "dies", I can see only the first log (that one with [findUser]).
There is a funny thing before this happen: the pool start to decrease its opened connections. Starts with 10, then decrease using only 3 connections, then 2 connections, then just one connection until it dies.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: Idle connections may be terminated by a firewall.  Fix the firewall. If it's an option enable tcp keep alive so you can detect and/or prevent the connection from being closed on you.  If the pool detects the connection died, it should reopen it, on next query if need be.  If your code closes the connection then I think it's more a judgement call if that is something the pool to address or if you need to fix your app.

Comment: Hi @AllanWind, is it possible that this firewall terminates my idle connections after 2,5h? NB: I can query mysql, I have results back at start, but after 6/7 hours the pool starts to lose these connections until no ones open.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @AllanWind why the pool cannot open a new connection? Do you have any idea? My code just release the connection (so it can reuse), not destroy or end. Thanks a lot

Comment: My guess is that's the idle connections that are timed out.  The next step would be to capture the network traffic.  I would write an app, so you don't get a ton of data for a 2.5 hr dump.  Good luck!

Comment: @AllanWind Thanks, man. I'll fill you in.

Answer (score 1):

It was a missing connection.release() after a connection.commit()